# Driver is not working as expected

Tags: transforms, drivers

I have put a driver in the z rotation of an empty and made the variable a single property, where the path is the count in the array modifier.
My expression is `360/variable`. I see that the driver value is as expected, but the rotation of the object is not like the driver value. Why this is happening and how can I fix it?

[image: driver with wrong rotation value]
The one with orange is right but the blue is wrong.

Comment: @someonewithpc that is not the problem at all, in fact that is not how drivers work. See [my answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/18653/2217) for what is going on here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That comes from the difference between degrees and radians. For some reason, the drivers evaluate rotation in *radians* no matter what the  Units are set to in the Scene settings.

To get the expression working you have to convert radians to degrees. So your expression would be.
`360/Array * 0.0174532925` or `360/Array * pi/180` or even shorter `pi*2/Array`

There are 0.0174532925 radians in 1 degree, so just multiply your expression by the difference between degrees and radians.

Comment: Blender exclusively uses radians internally, so when working with the python api to manipulate internal values you have to use radians too. The scene setting just translates the units in the interface, AFAIK it doesn't do anything to the internal handling of units.